# Embedded Sounds cut off early

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, embed

I have a combined Flash Builder/Flash Pro project. Because of the hassles involving in maintaining sound assets on the timeline, my sounds are all embedded into Class files, like:

```
[Embed (source="/mp3/Welcome_01_V.mp3", mimeType="audio/mpeg")]
private static const WELCOME_1:Class;
```

These files are then referenced by the base Classes for the symbols that need them, embedded for Actionscript on Frame 10 (because the second frame label is on Frame 10 to give space for you to read the first one).

What I'm finding is that a few of these Sounds don't play all the way through, but the SoundChannel dispatches the "soundComplete" event, and its final position matches the Sound's length.

All sounds are converted from wav to mp3 at 44Hz / 16 kbps. I faked out the compiler to avoid a reference to Flex by including a dummy SoundAsset that extends Sound.

I don't know what other steps to take to debug this. Is there a way to figure out whether the problem is on the compile side or on the run side?

## Updated

More things I have tried:

- Looked at the Size report: The nonworking sounds were smaller in
  their embedded form than the source mp3
- Got rid of my own BitmapAsset and let Flash link in the Flex Framework and do whatever that does (definitely worse)
- Dropped the encoding from 44 kHz to 22 kHz (no improvement or worse)
- Dropped the bit rate to 8kbps (the lowest dbPowerAmp, the tool I use, supports). This usually helps somewhat, but I still usually use a word or two from the end of the file
- Dropped both parameters in the encoding. This helped a few that just dropping the bit rate didn't, but not all files. Plus it sounds tinny.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807462/embedded-mp3-in-actionscript3-wont-play-all-the-way-through ?

Comment: Just a thought - The position is the number of milliseconds already played, is this equal to the length of the sound as visible in a mp3 player? Also, when you embed, the final swf size is always more than the sound size (bytes, I mean). That is another way to check that the entire sound is embedded

Answer (score 1):

For Flash audio, I recommend importing the sound assets into a FLA using wav files if you have the high quality source wavs. Otherwise, you can consider converting your mp3 into a wav as well. Then set the FLA export settings to the quality you want and Flash will convert your wavs into its own format at the quality you set with hopefully less issues.

Once you do that, you can export the sound symbol for actionscript in your library and set a class name just like how you would embed it.

One other trick I use is I have one FLA just for sound assets which can be used to store as big waves as I want. And when I export that, it becomes a small SWF file which I can then embed in my main application. That way, I never have Flash reconvert the wavs to the swf every single time I export the swf. Instead it just copies the swf data which is much faster as well.

```
    [Embed(source="Audio/Sfx.swf", symbol="WELCOME_1_WAV")]
    private static const WELCOME_1:Class;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having audio cut off issues in Flash Pro, you may want to check your frame rate.

I had an issue with sounds cutting off (in Flash pro CC 2014). My issue turned out to be related to the frame rate being set to 25 rather than the default 24. I have been using 25 to resolve an issue unrelated to anything in this project, so my solution was to change the FPS to 24, which invoked the necessity to move all of the synchronized animations to re-align with the corresponding audio.

Why long(ish) audio tracks get cut off at the end when the frame rate is at 25 regardless of using proper keyframing is a mystery. This solved the symptoms however, so if you are having audio cut off issues in Flash Pro, you may want to check your frame rate.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was using the default 24 fps and the audio was being played through code, not on the timeline. But thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

My symptoms were specifically when an audio clip was particularly long, and deep into the time line.

What worked for me: I opened the audio files in an audio editor and added a few seconds of silence to the end.

Good luck! - J.Hall