# Adobe AIR mp3 cut short

Tags: actionscript-3, air, mp3

I'm trying to play MP3 file of about 4 seconds.
I have a problem that the playing of the sound cut short.

I have Mac and when checking the Get Info of two files, one that works great and this problematic one I notice the one that works great has 2 Audio channel (as written in Finder Get Info window) and the problematic has only 1.

Is it possible Adobe AIR does not handle 1 channel mp3 files well?

Comment: Have you tried converting the problematic mp3 to wav and see if there's a difference?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321441/embedded-sounds-cut-off-early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the mp3 file was mono, it had only one channel of audio in it. 
I've use audacity app to duplicate the audio channel and save the mp3 as stereo.

This solve the problem and now the full length of the audio file is playing.