# as3 embed sound cannot convert to type Class?

Tags: actionscript-3, load, embed

embedding a sound into my .swf..

```
[Embed(source='/audio/files/sp_worm.mp3')]
private var sf_warp_finish:Class;
```

the reading it here:

```
var sndClass:Class;
if (soundId == "sf_warp_finish") sndClass = new sf_warp_finish();
```

and am receiving this error:

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert GameSoundManager_sf_warp_finish@a94eb31 to Class.
```

Not sure why this isn't working- any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sf_warp_finish is actually the class with your embedded data; when you call new(), you instantiate it and now you have an object (not a Class object).

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/SoundAsset.html
for an example.

Comment: When I change it to sndClass = sf_warp_finish I can't seem to convert it to a Sound Object to play the sound? What am I missed??

Comment: @Lagoo87 Yes, I noticed a similar problem: the mp3 I have available doesn't play. Could it be a situation like in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807462/embedded-mp3-in-actionscript3-wont-play-all-the-way-through) ? Mine is 128 kbps and has an embedded image.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense- thanks @Luis!
I did not test it, but instead compiled my audio files in a .swc and accessed them via that.

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
var snd:Sound;
if (soundId == "sf_warp_finish") snd = new sf_warp_finish() as Sound;
if (snd)
    snd.play();
```